# Is there a way to determine if a stock has weekly vs monthly options?

Tags: options

For stocks/etfs that are optionable, is there a way to determine if they offer weekly or only monthly options without having to look at the option chain? I believe all optionable stocks/etfs have monthly options that expire on the 3rd Friday of the month so that would not be too hard to determine.

Also SPY has options that expire within the week, is there any other stocks/ETFs like this?

Question: I'm trying to figure if there is a metric that can determine if the underlying offers weekly & monthly or just monthly options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cboe offer two symbol directories for download at:
http://www.cboe.com/trading-resources/symbol-directory

http://www.cboe.com/trading-resources/symbol-directory/equity-index-leaps-options
here:
http://www.cboe.com/trading-resources/symbol-directory/weeklys-options

Both of the above pages allow you to download the underlying stock symbol in CSV format.

The first one also has a field "Product Types" which shows if weekly options and LEAPS are offered.

Note too the "cycle" field, which shows whether the options are monthly, bi-monthly, quarterly etc too.